# Release object after return?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Say I have an object initialized right before a method's return statement...

```
MyObj* myObj = [[MyObj alloc] initWithOpt1:opt1 withOpt2:opt2];
return myObj;
```

Is it possible to `release` it after the return statement? Doing so before defeats the purpose of init'ing it to begin with, right? Otherwise, what's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autorelease was created precisely to solve this problem.

```
MyObj* myObj = [[MyObj alloc] initWithOpt1:opt1 withOpt2:opt2];
return [myObj autorelease];
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Answer (score 3):

Just do

```
return [myObj autorelease];
```

that's it!

Answer (score 0):

While

```
return [myObj autorelease];
```

works it is better coding educate to simply

```
return myObj;
```

and then when you create the object do it with an autorelease on it.

```
MyObj *my_obj = [[[MyObj alloc] initWithOpt1:opt1 withOpt2:op2] autorelease];
```

and the reason for this is because autorelease is saying that when this function is over I want to release this object. So using

```
return [myObj autorelease];
```

is not the only way.